# Adobe plugin trouble

Tags: add-on

I am running Blender 3.2.0 I am trying to install the adobe 3D substance plugin. I have no problem adding: 'Substance3DInBlender' however, when I try to add on the Integration Tools, it just won't upload. any suggestions? I do not get an error message, I just get a notification (see red writing) that I need to upload the Integration Tools, I do this, and then nothing changes. thanks very much, Kelly

[image]

Comment: Try reading the [instructions for installation](https://www.adobeprerelease.com/beta/68A24EE2-2EA8-416F-D95B-23B8E64E5DE8) on the Adobe website, I can't share a direct link to the page since the beta seems to require sign-in, so you might have to jump some hoops, but it tells you exactly what to do. it is all spelled out very clearly. This has nothing to do with Blender itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.

I accidentally tried installed the Integration tools first, I was having trouble. I ended up deleting the addon in blender, opening the task manager and ending the process of the `substance_remote_something.exe` process. I can't remember the exact name of this process. But once I deleted it, I tried the installation procedure again and it worked.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. Since I accidentally tried installed the Integration tools first, I was having trouble. I ended up deleting the addon in blender, opening the task manager and ending the process of the substance_remote_something.exe process. I can't remember the exact name of this process. But once I deleted it, I tried the installation procedure again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well, but I got it working. Try installing the program directly from your downloads folder instead of dragging the Integration Tools folder to the desktop. Then it should sync properly.